# How to handle org.hibernate.StaleStateException?

Tags: hibernate, rest, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, ejb

I use REST APIs  which talk to database.

Using Hibernate with Wildfly 10.1.0

When I do concurrent update I get following exception;

What is the proper solution for this?
Should I send any error code to the client or should I handle at the backend?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67)
```

**Edit:**

```
public void saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
        Session session = null;
        try {
             session = getSession();
             session.clear();
             session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
             session.flush();

        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            log.error("Error when save or update." + entity.getCode(), ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw new HibernateException(ex);
        }
    }
```